# Passing encoded link in cURL

Tags: javascript, curl

I am trying to cURL a previously encoded URL in JS

It works when the URL is not encoded in js, like https://www.google.com
It does not work when the URL is encoded like https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

```
var link = "https://www.google.com";
var encodedLink = encodeURIComponent(link); // https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
var cmd = "curl -i " + encodedLink;
var headers = execCommand(cmd, false); // error
```

Comment: And you can't decodeURI or decodeURIComponent it before passing it to curl? Or are you expecting curl to decode it? Or is the problem that if you do decode it you then need to do some escaping to make it work on the shell?

Comment: I wanted to make sure I'm curl-ing the exact URL somebody has put in the HTML Code (so including odd characters, spaces) because the whole point is to detect the wrong ones (404s etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `encodeURIComponent` on whole URLs. Use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) instead. `encodeURI` detects what needs to be encoded and what doesn't need to. Its output can be passed to `curl` or [`fetch`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) without errors.

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('http://dont.encode.before?a=encode me'));
console.log(encodeURI('http://dont.encode.before?a=encode me'));
```

Comment: I'd guess OP is getting the URI from a parameter in a different URI, though, e.g. `/login?returnTo=https%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com`. But decoding and re-encoding with encodeURI is a nice solution.

Comment: Thank you Sir, it works now! Now I only need to work out how to include spaces in the regex I use for finding URLs in a block of text, but that's another story

Comment: Warning: as a rule of thumb, *never* use encodeURI, because encodeURI has to make guesses as to what part of GET variables are part of the name, and what part of GET variables are part of the value, for example encodeURI will get this wrong: `encodeURI("http://foo.com/?name=AT&T")` - but encodeURIComponent, which doesn't do any guessing whatsoever, gets this right: `"http://foo.com/?name="+encodeURIComponent("AT&T");` - rule of thumb: never use encodeURI, always use encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1):

> It does not work when the URL is encoded like https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

then decode it first,

```
link=decodeURI(link)
```

but you also need to escape that url before passing it as a command line argument, in PHP one would use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php), but here is a javascript port of it: http://locutus.io/php/exec/escapeshellarg/

```
function escapeshellarg (arg) {
  //  discuss at: http://locutus.io/php/escapeshellarg/
  // original by: Felix Geisendoerfer (http://www.debuggable.com/felix)
  // improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //   example 1: escapeshellarg("kevin's birthday")
  //   returns 1: "'kevin\\'s birthday'"

  var ret = ''

  ret = arg.replace(/[^\\]'/g, function (m, i, s) {
    return m.slice(0, 1) + '\\\''
  })

  return "'" + ret + "'"
}
```

the code should read

```
var cmd = "curl -i " + escapeshellarg(encodedLink);
```